# Android - programmatically enable speakers while on call for Huawei

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Idea is to enable speakers on the phone while the user is on the call.
So first I listen for `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` state, then with 2 seconds delay I call following code piece:

```
val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

if (!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn) {
      audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
      audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
}
```

This works well on Samsung, but for some reason, does not work on `Huawei P20 Pro`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are they running the same Android version?

Comment: Both phones use Android 10.

Comment: @MaartinAndroid not to be greedy or anything, but could you award me the bounty? The bounty will be lost with just 1 upvote, you need 2 upvotes to get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably not take no for an answer. But I think you are out of luck here. I have seen multiple occurrences of the problem you are describing and no fixes are described. In any case, it is clear that the standard Android Audiomanager does not work for Huawei phones. (for now, Huawei may come with a fix in the future)

However, I did find [this link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Media-Guides/audio-introduction) to a so called 'Audio Engine' in the documentation of Huawei. The documentation is not that elaborate, but you might just try to explore the library.

Still, that might work, but you'd have to detect which brand of phone you're using, that might be outside your scope and introduce other defects, but it is a possibility.